# Jqgrid pager shows wrong numbers

Tags: jqgrid, pager

I used jqgrid 1.7.2 on my project, it loads data correctly, but there is a small error in pager. it shows the correct number of record. And i split page by 50 rows. When I drag scrollbar slowly, (for trigging the pager) it shows 1-100 instead of 51-100. But if I drag it fast, shows 51-100. How can i fix this error. Thanks for helps...

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? Is it jqGrid 3.7.2 published more as 4 yeas ago or some more old version 1.7.2? Which web browser you use? Internet explorer 5? Do you tried to use more recent version of jqGrid? Sorry, but if you want that your code works with *current* versions of known web browsers you should update components which you use.

Comment: Thanks for reply Oleg, I used version 1.7.2, I used IE 9 and Google Chrome 38.0.2125. Absolutely I'm asking about the current version has this error or not. I didn't try to use current version because I have lots of pages made with using jqGrid, so if the error fixed with current version, I'll upgrading jqGrid version...

Comment: You are welcome! I have no jqGrid 1.7.2 so I can't help you here. I still believe that you are wrong about the version number of jqGrid. You should open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You will see the version number in the comment included at the beginning of it.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake about the version. The version of jqGrid 4.6.0.

Comment: Nope i have no solution...